# JPA: @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER), pagination and duplicates

Tags: java, sql, jpa, eclipselink

I use eclipselink as a JPA provider. I have an entity Article which has many Authors (this field is marked `@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)`). Article and authors are loaded together using only one sql query (JOIN).

To work with pagination I use the following code:

```
String queryString="SELECT DISTINCT e FROM Article e LEFT JOIN FETCH e.authors";
Query query = em.createQuery(queryString);
query.setHint("eclipselink.join-fetch", "e.authors"); 
query.setFirstResult(position);
query.setMaxResults(amount);
```

When setFirstResult and setMaxResults are used they, as I understand, define `limit part` in sql query. As a result I have two problems:

1. When I want to get 10 articles I get only two articles where the first article has 4 authors, and the second one has 6 authors
2. Article duplication - I have one article with different authors on different pages.

How to solve such problem?

Comment: that's a bug in your JPA provider. The firstResult/maxResults should apply to the Article objects, irrespective of whatever else is being fetched. Raise a bug if there isn't one already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FirstResult and and MaxResult do not work as you would expect when using fetch JOINs over collections as they are database SQL performance operations as described [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Pagination).

Don't use a fetch join over a collection mapping if you need absolute pagination results - use [batch fetching](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/QueryOptimization#Batch_Reading_.28Fetching.29) instead.  This will use 2 queries, allowing the first to correctly return the required rows with pagination, and the second to return the rows required for the collection relationship. Specify the IN or [batch.type](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/q_batch_type.htm#BABFGHAA) be used to limit the secondary query.